# Jquery removing unidentifiable/illegal characters from string

Tags: c#, jquery, regex, illegal-characters

I have a string that I am copying from word document and then passing it to my text area.
The issue is that the string contains a character that appears to be Right quotation mark but jquery is unable to identify it.

I am using the following regex

```
return inputValue.match("^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 \’\‘\@\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\-\=\{\}\:\;\'\,\.\?\|\/\~\`\n]+$") == null ? true : false;
```

The unidentifiable strings here are

```
\’\‘
```

When I check same regex while debugging in firebug I get it as

```
return inputValue.match("^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 \ \ \@\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\-\=\{\}\:\;\'\,\.\?\|\/\~\`\n]+$") == null ? true : false;
```

Please note that the  `\’\‘` are now  `\ \` in jquery and hence its always failing.. 
I checked out further and the character comes out with Ascii Value of

```
&#8216;
```

and

```
&#8217;
```

Please let me know a way to change these to normal single quote i.e of Ascii value 39.
or to completely remove it from the string

I know I can use a replace function to do the same, but the issue is that its not just related to single quote.. it can be any other character in future also..

So I need a foolproof solution for these illegal/Unidentifiable characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using their hex equivalent (also make your string literal with `@`):

```
return inputValue.match(@"^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 \u2018\u2019@!#$%^&*()_+={}:;',.?|/~`\n-]+$") == null ? true : false;
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`\u2018` is for `‘` and `\u2019` is for `’`.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/b8X8Jm)